# Quasar table - columns sorting always false, the small arrow direction not changing

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I am using server pagination with Quasar table. Pagination ref is :

```
const pagination = ref({
    sortBy: 'desc',
    descending: false,
    page: 1,
    rowsPerPage: 10,
    rowsNumber: 0,
});
```

Q-table is:

```
<q-table
    :dense="isTableDense"
    v-model:selected="selected"
    v-model:pagination="pagination"
    :columns="columns_wideview"
    :rows="localRows"
    :visible-columns="visibleColumns_wideView"
    @request="onRequest"
    row-key="id"
    selection="multiple"
    title="Ügyfelek"
    ref="tableRef"
    no-data-label="Nincs adat..."
    binary-state-sort
>
```

Whenever I click on the column header, the direction of arrow is not changing (always up):

[image]

The onRequest function:

```
<q-table
    :dense="isTableDense"
    v-model:selected="selected"
    v-model:pagination="pagination"
    :columns="columns_wideview"
    :rows="localRows"
    :visible-columns="visibleColumns_wideView"
    @request="onRequest"
    row-key="id"
    selection="multiple"
    title="Ügyfelek"
    ref="tableRef"
    no-data-label="Nincs adat..."
    binary-state-sort
>
```

The onRequest function:

```
function onRequest(props1) {
    const { page, rowsPerPage, sortBy, descending } = props1.pagination;
 
    console.log(descending);  // --> ALWAYS PRINTING FALSE AND ARROW NOT TURNING
  
    filter.sortby = props1.pagination.sortBy;
    pagination.value.rowsNumber = props.clients.total;

    axios
        .get(route('clients.index'), {
            params: {
                page: page,
                filter: filter,
            },
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
       
            localRows.value = [...data.data];

            pagination.value.rowsNumber = data.total;
            pagination.value.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
            pagination.value.page = page;
            pagination.value.descending = descending;

        })
       
}
```

Whatever I did the arrow never turns and the expression:

```
props1.pagination.descending
```

always false. Can someone see where I am troubled?